# Are asynchronous operations on Azure snapshots automatically "queued"?

Tags: powershell, azure

I am writing a script that:

- takes a snapshot of a data disk that is attached to a running VM
- copies the snapshot to different storage account (using `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy`)
- deletes the snapshot

This seems to work as it is.  However, I note that the copy operation is asynchronous, and is not likely complete by the time I run the command to delete the snapshot.  The snapshot appears to be gone right away.

Do I need to wait for the copy status of the blob to be 'complete' before I delete the snapshot, or does the Azure infrastructure handle this in the background?  I am not getting any exceptions thrown in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to complete your blob-copy operation prior to deleting the snapshot.

If you're concerned about storage costs due to leaving snapshots around longer than necessary, consider the following:

- snapshots don't initially take up space
- snapshots only accrue space when pages in the original blob are modified
- storage costs are amortized daily, so even if you left a snapshot around for a few hours, *and* pages were changed, an extra 1GB accrued would be almost negligible cost-wise (e.g. with locally-redundant storage, daily cost is 0.002 / GB - and that's list price, no discounts applied).

Comment: It's not a cost issue.  I just wanted to clean up after the copy operation.  I will add code my script to wait for the copy to complete.